# Cálculo obtención de las fechas de los recibos de una factura aplazada

Tags: php, matemáticas, algoritmos

A ver si alguien puede ayudarme. Tiene que haber una forma mucho más sencilla de hacerlo, y que no me dé los errores que me da a mi.

Necesito dar con un cálculo que, dada una **fecha de factura** y unos **plazos**, me permita obtener las **fechas de vencimiento (fechas de recibos)** de dicha factura aplazada, bien tenga uno o más recibos, con diferentes tipos de aplazamientos:

> - 30/60/90  (a los 30, 60 y 90 días desde la fecha de factura respectivamente)
> - 15/30/45/60
> - 60/90
> - etc

Hay que tener en cuenta que un cliente puede por defecto **NO** tener definido ningún **día de pago** concreto al mes, en cuyo caso, los vencimientos van conforme al día de la factura, pero teniendo en cuenta cada mes como 30 días.

Ejemplo:

fecha de factura: 31/05/2016 con forma de pago aplazada y vencimiento a 15/30/45/60 días.
Los vencimientos serían en:

> - 15/06/2016
> - 30/06/2016
> - 15/07/2016
> - 31/07/2016

Si la fecha fuera: 05/05/2016 con misma forma de pago:

> - 20/05/2016
> - 05/06/2016
> - 20/06/2016
> - 05/07/2016

***Notar que no se tiene en cuenta si un mes tiene 31 o 28/29 días para que no bailen las fechas de cada vencimiento.***

El segundo caso posible es que el cliente **SI** tenga definidos dos **días de pago**, por ejemplo, 05 y 20 de cada mes, en cuyo caso, el vencimiento caería en el día 10 o 20 más próximo al plazo.

Ejemplo:

fecha de factura: 31/05/2016 con forma de pago aplazada y vencimiento a 15/30/45/60 días.
Los vencimientos serían en:

> - 20/06/2016
> - 10/07/2016
> - 20/07/2016
> - 10/08/2016

Pues bien, le he dado muchas vueltas y no consigo hacerlo funcionar en todos los escenarios. Ahora mismo lo tengo así:

```
<?php
class CalculadorVencimientos
{
    /**
     * @var int Día de pago 1 establecido por el cliente
     */
    private $diaPago1 = 0;
    /**
     * @var int Día de pago 2 establecido por el cliente
     */
    private $diaPago2 = 0;
    /**
     * @var string Fecha de la factura en formato yyyy-mm-dd
     */
    private $fechaFact;

    /**
     * @var boolean Flag que indica si el cliente tiene establecidos días de pago
     */
    private $tieneDiaPago = false;


    public function __construct($fechaFact, $diaPago1 = 0, $diaPago2 = 0)
    {
        $this->fechaFact = $fechaFact;
        $this->diaPago1 = $diaPago1;
        $this->diaPago2 = $diaPago2;

        $this->tieneDiaPago = $diaPago1 && $diaPago2;
    }   

    /**
     * Obtiene un array con las fechas de los vencimientos en formato yyyy-mm-dd
     * @param int[] $plazos
     * @return string[]
     */
    public function obtener($plazos)
    {
        $fechas = [];

        $fechaFact = explode('-', $this->fechaFact);
        $diasMesFactura = date('t', mktime(0, 0, 0, $fechaFact[1], 1, date('Y')));      

        foreach ($plazos as $i => $plazo) {

            // Cálculo para vencimientos múltiplos de 30 días de un mes
            if ($plazo % 30 == 0) {
                $mes = round($plazo / 30);

                $fecha = mktime(0, 0, 0, $fechaFact[1] + $mes, $fechaFact[2], $fechaFact[0]); 
            }
            // Resto (vencimientos a 15, 45 dias...)
            else {
                $mes = 0;
                if ($plazo > 30 && count($plazos) > 1 || $diasMesFactura - $fechaFact[2] < $plazo) {
                    $mes = floor($plazo / 30);
                    $plazo = abs($plazo - ($mes * 30));
                }

                $diasMes = date('t', mktime(0, 0, 0, $fechaFact[1] + $mes, 1, date('Y')));
                $offset = 30 - ($diasMes == 31 ? 0 : $diasMes); // offset para compensar la diferencia de días de un mes con respecto a 30

                if ($plazo + $fechaFact[2] < $diasMes) {
                    $offset = 0;
                }

                $dia = $fechaFact[2] == 31 ? 30 : (int)$fechaFact[2];
                $fecha = mktime(0, 0, 0, $fechaFact[1] + $mes, $dia + (int)$plazo - $offset, $fechaFact[0]);
            }

            // Hasta aquí tenemos calculada la fecha del vencimiento actual, 
            // pero ahora vemos si el cliente tiene especificados días de pago 

            $diaPlazo = date('d', $fecha);      
            $diaPago = $this->calcularDiaPago($diaPlazo);

            if ($this->tieneDiaPago) {
                if ($diaPlazo <= $diaPago){
                    $fecha=mktime(0, 0, 0, intval(date("m",$fecha)), $diaPago, date("Y",$fecha));
                }
                else {
                    $diaPago = $this->calcularDiaPago($diaPago);
                    $fecha=mktime(0, 0, 0, intval(date("m",$fecha)) + 1, $diaPago, date("Y",$fecha));
                }
            }

            $fechas[] = date('Y-m-d', $fecha);
        }       

        return $fechas;
    }


    /**
     * Obtiene el día de pago que toca para el plazo actual según caiga
     * @param int $diaPlazo
     * @return int
     */
    protected function calcularDiaPago($diaPlazo)
    {
        // El cliente no tiene ningún día de pago establecido? Entonces tomamos el día que caiga el plazo.
        if (!$this->tieneDiaPago) {
            return $diaPlazo;
        }
        // Si tenemos especificados los dos días de pago del cliente, obtenemos el más cercano hacia delante a la fecha del plazo
        else {
            if ($diaPlazo > $this->diaPago1 && $diaPlazo <= $this->diaPago2) {
                $diaPago = $this->diaPago2;
            }
            else {
                $diaPago = min($this->diaPago1, $this->diaPago2);
            }   
        }

        return $diaPago;
    }

}


/*******************************/
// Ejemplo: fecha factura 31/05/2016, cliente con forma pago 15/30/45/60 y sin días de pago específicos
$calculador = new CalculadorVencimientos('2016-05-31');
?>
<pre>
<?php
var_dump($calculador->obtener([15,30,45,60]));
?>
OUTPUT: (ERRÓNEO)
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(10) "2016-05-15"
  [1]=>
  string(10) "2016-07-01"
  [2]=>
  string(10) "2016-07-15"
  [3]=>
  string(10) "2016-07-31"
}
</pre>
<?php


// Ejemplo: fecha factura 31/05/2016, cliente con forma pago 30/60/90 y sin días de pago específicos
$calculador = new CalculadorVencimientos('2016-05-31');
?>
<pre>
<?php
var_dump($calculador->obtener([30,60,90]));
?>
OUTPUT: (ERRÓNEO)
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(10) "2016-07-01"
  [1]=>
  string(10) "2016-07-31"
  [2]=>
  string(10) "2016-08-31"
}
</pre>

<?php
// Ejemplo: fecha factura 30/04/2016, cliente con forma pago 30/60/90 y sin días de pago específicos
$calculador = new CalculadorVencimientos('2016-04-30');
?>
<pre>
<?php
var_dump($calculador->obtener([30,60,90]));
?>
OUTPUT: (OK)
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(10) "2016-05-30"
  [1]=>
  string(10) "2016-06-30"
  [2]=>
  string(10) "2016-07-30"
}
</pre>

<?php
// Ejemplo: fecha factura 30/04/2016, cliente con forma pago 15/30/45/60 y con días de pago 05 y 20
$calculador = new CalculadorVencimientos('2016-04-30', 5, 20);
?>
<pre>
<?php
var_dump($calculador->obtener([15,30,45,60]));
?>
OUTPUT: (ERRÓNEO)
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(10) "2016-05-20"
  [1]=>
  string(10) "2016-06-05"
  [2]=>
string(10) "2016-05-20"  // debería ser 2016-06-20   
  [3]=>
  string(10) "2016-07-05"
}
</pre>

<?php
// Ejemplo: fecha factura 31/05/2016, cliente con forma pago 15/30/45/60 y con días de pago 05 y 20
$calculador = new CalculadorVencimientos('2016-05-31', 5, 20);
?>
<pre>
<?php
var_dump($calculador->obtener([15,30,45,60]));
?>
OUTPUT: (ERRÓNEO)
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(10) "2016-05-20"
  [1]=>
  string(10) "2016-07-05"
  [2]=>
  string(10) "2016-07-20"
  [3]=>
  string(10) "2016-08-05"
}
</pre>
```

Alguien podría ayudarme a resolver este rompecabezas??

Comment: Creo que no queda claro cuál es el problema, ya que mencionas errores, pero no los incluyes en tu pregunta. Te recomiendo que dividas tu pregunta en partes más pequeñas o que ataques tus errores, uno en cada pregunta.

Comment: @toledano. Hola. Los errores los he detallado en los ejemplos del bloque de código. Hay fechas que no cuadran conforme al orden lógico que debería seguir según lo indicado en el enunciado.

Comment: PHP tiene un montón de métodos para tratar con fechas, creo que estás buscando algo como [DateTime::add](http://php.net/manual/es/datetime.add.php), que te permite sumar días (o meses, o años, ...) a cualquier fecha.

Answer (score 1):

Puede que uno de tus problemas, es que si tienes en cuenta los días de los meses, al calcular los dias, en la función obtener.

Puedes probar a calcular los dias con una función javascript similar a esta

```
sumaFecha = function(d, fecha)
{
   var Fecha = new Date();
   var sFecha = fecha || (Fecha.getDate() + "/" + (Fecha.getMonth() +1) + "/" + Fecha.getFullYear());
   var sep = sFecha.indexOf('/') != -1 ? '/' : '-'; 
   var aFecha = sFecha.split(sep);
   var fecha = aFecha[2]+'/'+aFecha[1]+'/'+aFecha[0];

  fecha= new Date(fecha);

  fecha.setDate(fecha.getDate()+parseInt(d));

  var anno=fecha.getFullYear();
  var mes= fecha.getMonth()+1;
  var dia= fecha.getDate();
  mes = (mes < 10) ? ("0" + mes) : mes;
  dia = (dia < 10) ? ("0" + dia) : dia;
  var fechaFinal = dia+sep+mes+sep+anno;
  return (fechaFinal);
}
```